# Any load balancers using Chrome's JavaScript engine?

Tags: apache-2.2, load-balancing, javascript, f5-big-ip

F5 has TCL which is horrific to program. A10 copied.

Are there any programmable load balancers out there that are looking forward? Node.js seems to have blazed the trail and proven it works and Google will keep things good on JIT front.

Comment: Something about this fills me with fear.  I have no idea exactly what it is.

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off topic per the updated [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Zeus Traffic Manager.  It uses a proprietary non-blocking language named 'TrafficScript', but it's styled like Javascript rather than TCL so it's a lot easier to get to grips with.

http://knowledgehub.zeus.com/articles/2010/08/16/trafficscript_why_create_a_new_language

Answer (score 0):

There is not yet, and I am not sure if there will be ever. Also, I can't see the point why JS is more suitable than TCL. TCL is absolutely perfect for this purpose.